# C++ multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I couldn't find where the bug is in the following program to print even and odd nos using two threads.Please suggest

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
pthread_mutex_t t1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
void* print_even(void*);
void* print_odd(void*);
static int data = 0;

int main()
{
    pthread_t a[2];
    pthread_create(&a[0],NULL,print_even,NULL);
    pthread_create(&a[1],NULL,print_odd,NULL);
    pthread_join(a[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(a[1],NULL);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void* print_even(void* p)
{
do{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&t1);
    if(data%2 != 0)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&t1);
    }
cout<<data;
data++;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
if(data > 10){
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&t1);
    break;
    }
pthread_mutex_unlock(&t1);
}while(1);
}
void* print_odd(void* p)
{
    do{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&t1);
    if(data%2 != 1)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&t1);
    }
    cout<<data;
}
    data++;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    if(data > 10)
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&t1);
        break;
    }
    }while(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problems are:

- Each thread needs to wait on a different condition variable, and signal the other thread's one. You have both waiting on the same one.
- You need to unlock the mutex after signalling, so the other thread can lock it and continue.
- You should re-check the condition after waking, in case the wakeup was spurious.

The loop in each thread should look more like

```
while (data <= 10) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&t1);
    while (data%2 != 0) {               // 1 in the other thread
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&t1);   // cond1 in the other thread
    }
    cout<<data;
    data++;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);        // cond in the other thread
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&t1);
}
```

I took the liberty of restructuring the loop to be less weird, and more obvious that the mutex is correctly unlocked each time. If you're not stuck with an ancient compiler, I'd recommend using the C++ threading library (with nice RAII-style locks) rather than messing around with Posix threads the hard way.